# Why IViewLocalizer no working with keyword {0}?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an asp.net core 5 project with `IViewLocalizer` for Localizer.

The string in Localizer has some dynamic keyword, it is used for component view.

I am about to use `String.Format` to solve this.

So I have to add some variable string in the localizer, for example:

```
Welcome to {0}
```

When I use the code below to render it in the view:

```
@string.Format(Localizer["Welcome"].Value, ShopName)
```

This string doesn't render any and blocks all the code after it.

It is so strange that Visual Studio 16.8.2 doesn't report any errors.

Soon I found a solution with this:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(Localizer["Welcome"].Value, ShopName))
```

However, I don't know what causes this problem and why `Html.Raw`solves it.

Could you please tell me more about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You try like this when you get data from localizer;

```
@Localizer.GetString("Welcome",new string[]{"Shop Name"});
```

Comment: Well, your way works also. Actually, I want to know why @string.Format(Localizer["Welcome"].Value, ShopName) no working.

Comment: I just tested your way with your inputs. And its working properly on me. I dont know why its not working on you .